# how to memoize nodes in a recursive cte query traversing a graph?

Tags: sql, recursion, ssms, common-table-expression

my database contains objects which are related in a tree-like structure (parent-child relations) but objects can have multiple parents (so it's not really a tree, but rather a graph).

I want to traverse the graph from a given starting object and list all related objects ob the starting object.

My table look like this:

[table and graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Motd7.png)

My recursive query should visit all parents and all children of a Node and repeats from there. The Problem is that i don't know how to remember the nodes i've already been, and thus i get into an endless recursion.

Here's the query i wrote (which does not remember the visited nodes):

```
With cte_Relatives(ident, parentIdent) 
AS (
SELECT start.ident, start.parentIdent
FROM tblRelatives start
WHERE start.Ident = 'C'

UNION ALL

SELECT  
        child.ident, 
        child.parentIdent, 
FROM tblRelatives AS child
JOIN cte_Relatives parent ON parent.ident = child.parentIdent

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    parent.ident,
    parent.parentIdent,
FROM tblRelatives AS parent
JOIN cte_Relatives child ON parent.ident = child.parentIdent


)

SELECT * FROM cte_Relatives
```

My problem is that ctes do not allow more than one recursive reference to cte_Recursion per union block.  Thus i cannot look if my new table already contains the ID, i'm looking at. Like this:

```
JOIN cte_Relatives child ON parent.ident = child.parentIdent AND parent.ident not in (Select ident from cte_Relatives)
```

How can i store the visited nodes?

P.s: I'm sorry, if this has already been asked, i didn't find a solution.

Comment: Can you please post a sample of a possible input and the desired output?